# References for the construction of various number types

Tags: reference-request, foundations

Hello I am a high school student currently reading through *Calculus* by Spivak which has been recommended by many people on this site. I was slightly disappointed by the first chapter in which properties of numbers are discussed. I value rigour highly and don't want to study learn calculus until I understand the abstract and axiomatic aspects of how numbers work. The author, for example, does not construct $\mathbb{N}$ from Peano's axioms, nor does he construct $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ as, respectively, equivalence classes of ordered pairs of natural numbers and integers. He doesn't talk about the field/ring axioms either. He also makes various assumptions which are bizarre considering how he is otherwise meticulous (closure under addition and multiplication, for example).

This leads me to my question: can someone suggest free, online references (class notes will suffice) which discuss the construction of various types of numbers from a rigorous standpoint?

Comment: Landau's *Foundations of Analysis* has what you want. I don't know where you can get it for free, but in less than a minute I found a used copy for $7 with free shipping in the USA.

Comment: You can see also : ITTAY WEISS, [The Real Numbers -  a survey of constructions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03467v1.pdf).